# How to reload table from tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to reload `tableView` from custom cell? Cell has two buttons inside if the button is clicked table should reload.
I was trying to add protocol inside `UITableViewCell` File and reload it once the button is clicked but the protocol function inside `UITableViewController` is not being called.

Here the code inside UITableViewCell:

```
protocol reloadTableDelegate  {
    func reloadTableonClick()
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   var delegate : reloadTableDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

     var button1Clicked = false
    var button2clicked = false


    @IBAction func button1Action(_ sender: Any) {
        button2clicked = true
        delegate?.reloadTableonClick()
    }
    @IBAction func button2Action(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.reloadTableonClick()
    }

}
```

This is what I am doing inside UITableView to reload table:

```
extension TableViewController : reloadTableDelegate {
    func reloadTableonClick() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]? What else have you tried so far?

Comment: are you setting the delegate in your cell for row?

Comment: Yupe , had added cell.delegate in didselectRow instead of cell for row

Comment: For what purpose,u r going to reload ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add an action to the button. You can do it like this:

```
if myButton.target(forAction: #selector(self.myButtonTapped()), withSender: nil) == nil { //Check that we don't add it multiple times
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myButtonTapped()), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

This line has to be inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Then in your view controller make a function like this:

```
func myButtonTapped() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

From the example you provided in your code you should also be setting the delegate to the cell. Meaning in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should set:

```
myCell.delegate = self
```

And in your view controller implement those methods like you're already doing.

Comment: I have created button action inside UITableViewCell file from where it will call delegate method located inside UITableView file which will intern reload that table (using protocols) but at present the protocol method is not being called

Comment: Can you please add an example of how you tried to set it up? It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing some code.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I had added mycell.delegate = self inside didselect row

Comment: No that's not okay. Because when the button is tapped the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called. Meaning your delegate will be null and that's why it's not calling your delegate method. You need to be setting it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Yeah i was aware of that but I did not noticed t at first.

Comment: So it's working now or still not? It should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

try adding tableView.reloadData() anytime it needs to update.

Comment: yeah i have added tableView.reloadData()